# Is it possible to do a several calculations in partition by statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do the following calculation in SQL Microsoft server,

```
(sum(value)/avg(Numberofmonths))*(avg(Numberofmonths)/12)) over (partition by year,Country) as totalsales
```

As I understand all variables are aggregated by partition by the statement, however, I got an error Incorrect syntax. How can I solve the problem?

Data is following and the output should be as in output column

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: If you have multiple windowed functions, each needs its own `OVER` clause. If you are doing something like this, you probably *don't* want windowed functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added data to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each window function needs an `over` clause:

```
((sum(value) over (partition by year, Country) /
  avg(Numberofmonths) over (partition by year, Country)
 ) *
 (avg(Numberofmonths) over (partition by year, Country) / 12)
) as totalsales
```

Or simplify this to:

```
(sum(value) over (partition by year, Country) / 12)
) as totalsales
```

Comment: `avg(Numberofmonths) over (partition by year, Country)` seems to appear in both the numerator and denominator, and that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I modified the answer suggesting simpler logic.

Comment: Your edit seems clearer now, and in any case your first answer is technically correct +1.